# Does SQL Server 2012/2014 Standard support Hot Add memory on a Hyper-V guest?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

In this support article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956893

The answer to Q7 says:

> Hyper-V Dynamic Memory is fully supported with SQL Server. Only SQL
>   Server versions and editions that support Hot Add Memory (Enterprise
>   and Datacenter) can see memory that is added by using Hyper-V Dynamic
>   Memory. **SQL Server 2012 Standard edition also recognizes Hot Add
>   memory when running in a virtual environment**.

The two sentences seem contradictory. Can anyone confirm if SQL Server ***Standard*** supports hot add memory when running on a Hyper-V guest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrasing might be confusing, however it means exactly what it says.

The Hot memory adding is a feature. Not a subject of limitations of the environment.

So what the article actually says is:

- You can only use the Hot add Memory feature in SQL Server Enterprise and Datacenter
- Standard version of SQL Server 2012 could detect memory being added to the system, however it does not allow for hot add memory to the SQL Server so the feature is turned off

In other words, no it doesn't work.
I guess somewhere in the Microsoft office there is a dev who really *really* wanted people to know it wasn't his fault that the feature is limited to Enterprise and Datacenter editions. But rather a part of the licensing.

Comment: Ok thanks so it doesn't work in Standard. That's the main question. I still don't understand the meaning of the highlighted sentence. Does 2012 Standard "recognize" hot add memory in some way that web edition doesn't?